# Failed to load desktop after upgrade ubuntu 16 gnome

Tags: gnome, 16.04, desktop-environments

I had ubuntu 15.10 gnome and I upgraded to ubuntu 16 gnome. At boot the login screen appears as usual but when I login the display goes blank and the desktop fails to load.
I have AMD graphics card.
I have no idea what to do so please help me fix it.
[image]

Comment: Type `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and see if can go into the terminal. If you are in terminal, type `gnome-shell` to start the GUI. (I am not completely sure , that is why i put this as a comment)

Comment: I have added a picture of the result of command gnome-shell